# multi-part identifier error when sorting

Tags: sql

```
Project nr      Task                  Task deadline    Task Type Production
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
456             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
456             Leave production      3 april 2013      Leave Production
456             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
123             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
123             Leave production      6 april 2013      Leave Production
123             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
789             packed                1 april 2013      Packed
789             Leave production      9 april 2013      Leave Production
789             Flight date           9 april 2013      Flight Date
```

I need a list like above I want to sort on the date of 'Leave production' The project nr has to stay in groups of 3 like the list above.

I already have this SQL. The list is working but the sort is not working. The error is:

> *The multi-part identifier "task.[task deadline]" could not be bound.*

I already had a suggestion but still errors. How do I get is sorted?

This is the list I get:

```
Project Nr     Task             TaskDate
0053           Packed           2013-02-05 17:00:00.000
0053           Leave Production 2011-04-26 17:00:00.000
0053           Flight Date      2011-04-22 17:00:00.000
0071           Leave Production 2011-06-24 17:00:00.000
0081           Leave Production 2012-03-09 17:00:00.000
0081-01        Leave Production 2012-03-09 17:00:00.000
```

This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT  
    [Project nr], Task, TaskDate
FROM    
    (SELECT   
        MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Packed' 
                  THEN [Task deadline] 
             END) AS Packed
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production' 
                  THEN [Task deadline]
             END) AS [Leave Production]
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date' 
                  THEN [Task deadline]
             END) AS [Flight Date]
     FROM 
        MSP_EpmProject_UserView 
     LEFT JOIN 
        MSP_EpmTask_UserView ON MSP_EpmProject_UserView.ProjectUID = MSP_EpmTask_UserView.ProjectUID 
     LEFT JOIN 
        MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView ON MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskUID = MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.TaskUID 
     LEFT JOIN 
        MSP_EpmResource_UserView ON MSP_EpmAssignment_UserView.ResourceUID = MSP_EpmResource_UserView.ResourceUID 
     WHERE 
        (MSP_EpmTask_UserView.TaskIsProjectSummary = 0) 
     GROUP BY 
        MSP_EpmProject_UserView.[Project nr]) data
UNPIVOT
    (TaskDate
       FOR [Task] IN ([Pack], [Leave Production], [Flight Date])
    ) piv
```

This line should do the sort:

```
ORDER BY data.[Task deadline]
```

but I get an error

> *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
>
>   The multi-part identifier "data.Taskdeadline" could not be bound.*

Comment: If you want to order by `[Leave Production]` - you need to specify `ORDER BY [Leave Production]` (not by `[Task Deadline]`) ....

Answer (score 0):

The subquery that you alias as `data` just simply isn't returning a column called `Taskdeadline`

As you can see from your SQL statement - that subquery contains the columns:

```
[Project nr]
Packed
[Leave Production]
[Flight Date]
```

but that's all - no `Taskdeadline` anywhere to be seen....

So therefore, quite obviously, you cannot use that non-existing column in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: I need to sort on [Leave Production] This gives the same error. taskdeadline was not the right example. Just what i tried out.